# Observe running time of a Java code in cmd prompt

Tags: java, instrumentation

I have a java class file in my hand and can simply able to run it from windows cmd to view the output. Only thing I need to observe the running time of this java program depending on different input parameters. I don't have the source code so I can not modify it to generate the running time for me. Please suggest possible way out to observe this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code of the class you are trying to instrument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in another class and run that. For example if your class (to which you dont have code) is called Runner then you may be currently running it as

```
java -jar jarContainingRunner.jar Runner
```

If you create another class that then calls Runner you can do anything in that class. For example you could call the class InstrumentedRunner.

```
public class InstrumentedRunner {

   public static void main(String... arg) {
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       new Runner().run();
       long dur = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
       System.out.format("Runner took %s milliseconds", dur);
   }
}
```

(I haven't tested the code above.)

You could then run

```
java -jar jarContainingRunner.jar;jarContainingInstrumentedRunner.jar instrumentedRunner
```

It would then run Runner's run method (assuming that is the method you want to time) and output the time it took.

Comment: I've tried and found that through this way I can not able to get the actual running time of the MyClass.class as it has always gone in the background and keep running. While the MyClassRunner can only shows the running time of itself. Any other idea??

Comment: Hi, sorry for this late post. I've figured out the solution with the help of Windows Power Shell commands and here it is.

PS C:\> Measure-Command {java MyClass 1000 1234}

Days              : 0

Hours             : 0

Minutes           : 0

Seconds           : 0

Milliseconds      : 692

Ticks             : 6925010

TotalDays         : 8.01505787037037E-06

TotalHours        : 0.000192361388888889

TotalMinutes      : 0.0115416833333333

TotalSeconds      : 0.692501

TotalMilliseconds : 692.501


where 1000 is the input size and 1234 is a random number seed.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can write a batch file and there you can call your java class but before this save start time in variable and after class finish `subtract` it with start time.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple Java program to observe this.
Use runtime executions within your new code and observe the execution time.

A sample overview of this new code:

```
//... before your class runs.
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar yourClass"); 
//... after your class runs.
```

Comment: I've tried and found that through this way I can not able to get the actual running time of the MyClass.class as it has always gone in the background and keep running. While the MyClassRunner can only shows the running time of itself. Any other idea??