# What's the best unit of measure for timing a system

Tags: java

I would like to time how long a program takes to execute in it's entirety. It's possible to time it with `System.nanoTime();` but what's the best unit of measure is best to analyze the program?

Comment: pfff, I use yoctoseconds

Comment: please, I use Doc's DeLorean!

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends on the nature of your program as to what resolution you need in your logging. As a general rule, I think milliseconds would be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with:

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
// do something
long t2 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(t2 - t1);
```

You could also use `System.currentTimeMillis()` (this might be the better fit), it really depends on the process you are trying to measure.

Comment: the result would be negative if you went back in time...

Comment: I assumed the OP would not undertake any type of time travel when I posted this answer.

Comment: Actually, @user1329572's suggestion is a totally legitimate reason _not_ to do this.  Certainly if you used `System.currentTimeMillis()`, you could genuinely get negative results here.

Answer (score 0):

Milliseconds are more common than nanoseconds as not every system has that degree of fidelity.

```java
long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Time passes...
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedMillis = t1 - t0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.nanoTime()` is not supported on older versions of the JVM. The precision of these is probably OS dependent as well. [This article](https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks) is quite interesting and explains more about this sort of thing

Personally I would use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as that is still pretty accurate and is supported by older VMs. If you want more precision then I think `System.nanoTime()` is the best you can get.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12367331/846476) `SO` post may be interesting to you too